# servicestack.redis c# out of memory

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, servicestack.redis

When using PooledClientManager in ServiceStack.Redis in C#, getting  the following error

**Insufficent memory within specified address space range to continue the execution of the program**

There is more than 8gb of ram, so i feel there is enough memory space availble in the system.

What might be the causes and how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it x86 target ? If yes, then here may be 2G per process limitation

Comment: it is x64 target only.

Comment: I can recommend to attach profiler and whatch on CLR heaps